# Netty http server will not provide GeoTrust intermediate certificates

Tags: java, netty, keytool

This is not a netty issue per say, but just hoping some extra eyes will help.

I got a wildcard certificate from GeoTrust. I did not create the certificate signing request. The certificate was provided to me by my admin as a PKCS12 file. I imported the certificate using the keytool command into a jks keystore and run my Netty server.

SSL works when connecting to the server, but the GeotTrust validation tool fails the test because the chain is not provided. (https://knowledge.geotrust.com/support/knowledge-base/index?page=content&id=SO9557&actp=LIST)

I even used keytool to import the primary and secondary certs into the JKS.

So basically SSL works but the intermediate chains are not provided by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok through some magic and pixie dust I got it working.

1- I took the provided pfx file imported into Windows Certificate Store (make sure to mark the key as exportable)

2- Re-exported the certificate (make sure to check export key and all certificates in path if available)

3- Import pfx to JKS keystore.